# Why isn't my chrome profile responding to driver commands?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\oacoo\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 4")

driver = webdriver.Chrome
('C:\\Users\\oacoo\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe', options=options)
```

Successfully opens my profile, it won't search for this website nor click any xpaths.

My chrome driver is located at  `C:\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe` but when I use that instead of `C:\\Users\\oacoo\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe` it won't open my profile, just a non signed-in version of chrome :(

If I use
`C:\\Users\\oacoo\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe`
instead it returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\oacoo\OneDrive\Desktop\bots\bot\xoldver\likesmodule\password reset\passcode.py", line 18, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\oacoo\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe', options=options)
  File "C:\Users\oacoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\oacoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "C:\Users\oacoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Users\oacoo\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

help me load a page using my chrome profile please!

Comment: what about your `chromedriver.exe`? where is located?

Comment: C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe

Comment: Reference that in your code

Comment: when i use that instead of C:\\Users\\oacoo\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe it wont even open my profile, just a non signed in ver of chrome :(

Comment: Try moving chrome driver.exe in the same folder as your python file